# How to allow to download application whose resolution are 600 x 1024( 7"tablet) or 800 x 1280 (tablet 10") and restrict other resolution device?

Tags: android

I want to allow only those devices to download my application whose resolution is 600 x 1024 for 7" tablet and 800 x 1280 for 10" tablet. How can i do it? I do some RnD and got some thing that i can restrict it from manifest.xml file. But I am not able to figure out which is my solution from two option?

1) `<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />`

2)  `<compatible-screens>
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal"/>
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge"/>
    </compatible-screens>`

which one should I use to allow only above resolution device and restrict other device to download my application?

Thanks,

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.devicemetrics.screenspecs

download this app...it will tell screen specs of desired device put those things on your manifest file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to calculate screen size first like

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

for more please refer this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Comment: I know it. But i want to restrict application to be downloaded from play whose resolution is not 600 x 1024 or 800 x 1280. How can i defined it in manifest.xml file?

Comment: I refer this link but its says that above code is only for Handset.is it work with tablet or only with mobile device?

Comment: just read more with that link which i give hope u will get more about this best of luck dude :)

Comment: I read it properly but having confusion which code i use from above 2 codes i have written.Thanks

Comment: i think u should try 1st coz many small devices have hdpi screen like hdpi is not only big screen phone it depends on resolution so i think u should go with 1st :) best of luck dude